# Unexpected results in executing SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, cnosdb

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM air 
WHERE station = "LianYunGang" 
LIMIT 1;
```

When I run the above SQL statement, I get an error

> 422 Unprocessable Entity,
> details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Schema
>
> error: No field named "LianYunGang". Valid fields are air.time,
> air.station, air.pressure, air.temperature, air.visibility."}

Expected results:

```sql
+---------------------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------+
| time                | station     | pressure | temperature | visibility |
+---------------------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------+
| 2023-01-14T16:00:00 | LianYunGang | 68.0     | 78.0        | 52.0       |
+---------------------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, e.g. column names. Use single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional values in query statements should be in single quotes, so the correct statement would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM air where station = 'LianYunGang' limit 1;
```

The above statement will return the correct result